# I'm getting an empty var after I do a foreach in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I get a empty result when really i should get 3500

```
 $transcationhist = Transcationhistorique::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->pluck('amount');
    
 $amount = 0 ;

 foreach ($transcationhist as $p) {

    $amount = $amount + $p['amount'];

 }
```

Comment: put this in your code and show us what you got: ```dd($transcationhist)```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the value of `$transcationhist`?

Comment: Did you really spell amount as `ammount` on your table?

Comment: yes and i get this array [500,1000,1000,1000] like this

Comment: Then its `$ammount = $ammount + $p;` or `$ammount += $p`

Comment: Why dont use `Transcationhistorique::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->sum('ammount')`;

Comment: RiggsFolly and Davit the two reponse is correct thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to sum amount, tat case use this code

```
$amount = Transcationhistorique::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->sum('amount');
```

or you can use this

```
$transcationhist = Transcationhistorique::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
    ->pluck('amount');
$amount = $transcationhist->sum();
```

And finally if you want to use foreach then use this code

```
$transcationhist = Transcationhistorique::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
    ->get(['amount']);

 $amount = 0 ;

 foreach ($transcationhist as $p) {
    $amount = $amount + $p['amount']; // or $p->amount
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pluck would return a flat array in your case, use it that way:

```
$transcationhist = Transcationhistorique::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->pluck('amount');

 $amount = 0 ;

 foreach ($transcationhist as $p) {

    $amount += $p;

 }
```